# Issue with loop: argument of length 0

Tags: r, loops

I've tried working on this loop and come out with the below errors. I'm not sure if I can provide data, if needed I'll do my best to obfuscate the data. Here is the loop I am trying to use, any tips on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated as I haven't found a viable solution yet. The exact error is below the code.

```
decay_function = function(df)
{
  df <- df[order(df$department,df$product,df$region,df$monthnum),]
  for(mk in 1:ncol(levels_department)) {
    newdata <- df[which(df$department==as.character(levels_department[,mk])), ]
    levels_product<-as.data.frame(t(levels(as.factor(newdata$product))))
    for(md in 1:ncol(levels_product)){
      newdata <- newdata[which(newdata$product==as.character(levels_product[,md])), ]
      levels_region<-as.data.frame(t(levels(as.factor(newdata$region))))
      for(dm in 1:ncol(levels_region)){
        newdata <- newdata[which(newdata$region==as.character(levels_region[,dm])), ]
        for(i in 1:(nrow(newdata)-1)){
          start_month = newdata$monthnum[i]
          end_month = newdata$monthnum[nrow(newdata)]
          row_vector = c()
          decay_vector = c()
          for(j in 5:ncol(newdata)){
            k = 0
            for(l in start_month:end_month){
              distance_initial = (l - start_month)
              vector_increment = (l - (start_month-1))
              decay_rate = (0.5)^((1/halflife)*distance_initial)
              decay_value = (decay_rate)*(newdata[[i,j]])
              k = k + decay_value
            }
            df2[i,j] = k
          }
          print(df2)
        }
        if (mk=='1' & md=='1' & dm=='1'){
          outdata<-df2
        } else {
          outdata<-rbind(outdata,df2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output_data = decay_function(tempone)
```

> Error in start_month:end_month : argument of length 0

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(monthnum = c(33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33), Region = c(2251, 
2251, 2251, 2251, 2251, 2251), Department = c("Softlines", "Softlines", 
"Softlines", "Softlines", "Softlines", "Softlines"), Product = c("T-Shirt", 
"Jacket", "Sweat Shirt", "Tank Top", "Sweat Pants", "Mens Jeans"
), Incentive_Amount = c(5742.43, 108006.61, 459076.67, 34006, 
141632.42, 29580.38), Leads_T1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), DCLeads = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0), PhoneLeads = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T3_CRM_Leads = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Leads_Third = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: You have about five nested loops which is going to make that really difficult to debug (especially if you don't provide data). In any case, have you tried to step through the function and find out what happens when you assign `start_month` and `end_month`, because that's probably where something is going wrong.

Comment: @heds1 I added some sample data, I hope its enough.

Comment: what is your function trying to accomplish with the data? Please explain more...

Comment: @Sathish I'm trying to add a decay function for seasonal factors

Comment: Can you comment on each line what you are trying to do? Use `#` to comment the code. It will help us understand your decay function.

Comment: @Sathish I took your earlier advice and redid the loop. I will post the answer tonight after I have a chance to obfuscate some of the variables.